# React how to pass state between components

Tags: reactjs

I have two components in different class in a react app. I need to call a function in one class from clicking a button in another class.

```
changeTitle () {
  this.setState({header: 'New title' });
}
```

I tried to use import.

```
import Material  from './Material'

<Link to="/Material">  
<button className='button' id='button-1' />
<label className='label'>وحدة الوطن</label>
```

Any idea please how to do this ?

Comment: Are the two class components related??

Comment: declare event handler function in parent component and pass that down as props to the button component and in button component assign the function to the button onClick like onClick={this.props.functionFromParent} so when you click button here this will trigger the functionFromParent in the parent component. This is called callbacks in react

Comment: no they are not

Answer (score 0):

Assume the below function you have in Parent component called Title.js and the button in child component called Button.js

```
 changeTitle () {
      this.setState({header: 'New title' });
}
```

So import Button component in Title.js and call Button by sending changeTitle function as props

```
import Button from “./Button”;

 changeTitle () {
    //this function is called when the button is clicked in Button.js component
      this.setState({header: 'New title' });
}

 <Button onChangeTitle={this.changeTitle} />
```

Now in Button.js component assign the function to the button onClick like onClick={this.props.functionFromParent} so when you click button here this will trigger the functionFromParent in the parent component. This is called callbacks in react

```
   <button onClick={this.props.onChangeTitle} className='button' id='button-1' />
```

Make sure you bind changeTitle function in constructor like

```
  this.changeTitle = this.changeTitle.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

in **Material** class you can just call `changeTitle ()` in render class or in a lifecycle method like this:

```
componentDidMount(){
    changeTitle()
}
```